# How to deploy ARM Templates within an Azure Worker Role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure Worker Role. How can I execute an ARM template within this role?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do? That is: Are you attempting to deploy resources based on an ARM script, via code in your worker role instance? Are you trying to spin up worker role instances via ARM?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help. I am trying to deploy resources based on a ARM script within a worker role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the REST AP or the .NET SDK.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790568.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt418626.aspx